# Enhanced code coverage with Commons logging and Log4j 2.0

Tags: java, logging, code-coverage, log4j2, apache-commons-logging

I'm currently migrating from Log4j 1.2 to Log4j 2.
We use Apache Commons Logging 1.1 (JCL), with Log4j2 as implementation.

Now when executing unit tests, statements like

```
 if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
   log.info("example");
 }
```

will show up as uncovered lines in the coverage report if log log level is too high (e.g. WARN in this examole), as the `if` body wont be executed.

In Log4j 1 someone of my company thus wrote a custom logger that would return true for all `log.isXXXEnabled()` methods if it detects that it is run from Maven Surefire, like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger;

public class Log4JEnhancedCoverage implements Log {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -8715529047111858959L;

  private final Log logger;

  private final boolean mavenRun;

  public LogEnhancedCoverage(String name) {
    this.logger = new Log4JLogger(_name);
    this.mavenRun = TestsRunContext.isMavenSurefireRun();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isTraceEnabled() {
    return (mavenRun) ? true : logger.isTraceEnabled();
  }

  @Override
  public void trace(Object message) {
   logger.trace(message);
  }

  // repeat for warn, info, etc
}
```

The effect is that each `isXXXEnabled()` block is executed, the log statement is redirected to log4j via a configuration file. Log4j itself will see that only messages of the specified log levels are shown, while code blocks for *all* levels are executed.
Old: The problem is as you can see that a Log4j logger implementation is instanciated directly from the impl package of JCL. (Yes, they ship their own adapter implementation!).

In my new setup, I'm using the log4j-jcl artifact and I do not know how to properly create a Log4j 2 compatible logger in the constructor.

*Update:* `log4j-jcl` ships with its own log factory which loads a log4j 2 specific logger implementation. Thus the configuration of `commons-logging` for a specific logger is not honored at all.

Comment: It's much simpler to just use a separate testing log4j2 config file than to use a wrapper class. Are you able to remove Log4JEnhancedCoverage from your code entirely?

Comment: Maybe you should get rid of those tests before your logging lines. Are you using expensive code in the logger line? If not the guard statement is not really usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply get the logger using the commons logging API rather than directly instantiating it and you'll be fine.

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
//REMOVE THIS: import org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger;

public class Log4JEnhancedCoverage implements Log {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8715529047111858959L;

    private final Log logger;

    private final boolean mavenRun;

    public Log4JEnhancedCoverage(String name) {
        //REMOVE THIS: this.logger = new Log4JLogger(name);
        this.logger = LogFactory.getLog(name);
        ...
```

Comment: Good idea, but it does not work as Log4j itself seems to be responsible for creating the logger. See my update above.

Comment: @user3001 it works when I put together an example project. You said yourself that you're using commons-logging as the framework layer and log4j2 as the implementation. Your update states "Thus the configuration of commons-logging for a specific logger is not honored at all." which does not make sense to me because commons-logging should have no configuration; only the implementation layer should have a config file.

Comment: In the `commons-logging.properties` file you can specify which logger implementation should be used, but the Log4j 2 JCL bridge does not honor that anymore.

Comment: Ah, yes I see what you meant now. That is true.